# Происхождение названия города Челябинска

Tags: топонимика

Что означает название города Челябинск и откуда оно взялось?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, в основе название лежит тюркское слово и мужское имя "челяби", что означает "благородный".

Answer (score 1):

ЧЕЛЯБИНСК, топоним

ЧЕЛЯБИНСК, топоним. Существует неск. версий его происхождения. Наиболее ранней является гипотеза, опубл. в 1863 исслед. А. В. Орловым, согласно к-рой Челябинскую крепость назвали по тат. дер. Селяба, стоявшей на р. Селябка. По мнению нек-рых ученых (У. К. Сафиулин, Г. Ф. Сатаров, Ю. Г. Подкорытов), деревню основал легендарный тат. герой Селямбей. Г. А. Турбин считал, что это была деревня тархана Таймаса Шаимова, имевшего почетное звание “челяби”. Согласно версии А. Тарусова, слово “Ч.” произошло от назв. р. Челябка, что в пер. с фарси (дари) значит “сорок губ”, “сорокоуст”. Антропоним Челеби в исламском мире относится к эпитетам со значением сильной, влият. личности (в пер. с тат. – “миловидный, красивый, солнцеподобный”). С другой стороны, допустима версия происхождения топонима от назв. реки, т. к. немалое число селений именовалось по рекам, вблизи к-рых они строились. У тюрк. народов было заведено называть реки по именам владельцев тех вотчинных земель, где они протекали. Противники данной версии отмечают, что во времена появления русских на Юж. Урале (кон. 17 – нач. 18 вв.) никаких селений вблизи р. Миасс не существовало, поскольку это была терр. башк. и казах. племен и жить рядом с ними было небезопасно. Во времена тат.-монгольского ига было распространено почетное имя-звание Челеби (Челубей). В истории можно найти множество подтверждений существования этого антропонима. Так, напр., Челибиром звали одного из батыров, служивших черниговским князьям. В 15 в. Турцией правил султан Мухамед Челяби. Известный тур. ученый 17 в. Хаджи Халифе носил псевдоним Кятиб Челяби. В пер. с тур. яз. на рус. “челяб” означает “Бог”, а “челяби” – “божественный”, “одаренный Богом”. В ср.-век. Азии так называли ученых и поэтов как людей, отмеч. Богом. Вполне вероятно, что на месте совр. Чел. находились вотчинные земли тюрк. героя Селяби-Челеби, с именем к-рого, скорее всего, и была связана версия происхождения назв. тат. дер. Селяба. См. также Легенды о Челябинске.
©http://www.book-chel.ru/ind.php?id=4366&what=card

Answer (score 0):

Я не историк, но где то в 70-х годах, когда я учился в школе, учитель истории так объяснил происхождение слова Челябинск: после продажи башкирским ханом русскому царю территоррии, которая сейчас называется Башкирия ( в русском произношении). была основана крепость на продолжении Великого шелкового пути, где иноземные торговцы челом били (кланялись представителю русского царя), место было челобитным и крепость стала называться Челябинском. А про слово "челяба" - как и кто в 18 веке мог подняться на высоту хотя бы птичьего полета, что бы увидеть эту яму (или ведро, территория ведь не маленькая.

Comment: >челом били   
  
Крайне сомнительно фонетически.  
Я опускаю сейчас даже ничем не мотивированные исчезновение М  и смягчение Л. Но есть общий принцип. Такие топонимы "дрейфуют" от непонятных к якобы "понятным". Так фингское Ладыпоги сьало Лодейныи полеи, многочисленные тюркские Кала (крепомть) - Калачами и проч. А у вас получается - наоборот. Русское название стало чем-то тнепонятным.

>что бы увидеть эту яму   
  
Что за яма?!